# delete post also attachments

Tags: posts, functions, attachments, customization

I am trying to delete a post with its all attachments. This is the function that i came up with right now;

```
function remove_post(){
            if(isset($_POST['post_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['post_id'])){
                $post = get_post($_POST['post_id']);
                if(get_current_user_id() == $post->post_author){ echo 'ee';
                    wp_delete_post($_POST['post_id']);
                }
            }  

            exit;
        }
```

This deletes the post but not the attachments link to that post also its not hard deleting, the post remains in the trash. So what do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this works

```
function remove_post() {

            if(isset($_POST['post_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['post_id'])) {

                $post = get_post($_POST['post_id']);

                if(get_current_user_id() == $post->post_author) { 


                     $args = array(
                             'post_parent' => $_POST['post_id']
                 );

                 $post_attachments = get_children($args);

                     if($post_attachments) {

                            foreach ($post_attachments as $attachment) {

                                      wp_delete_attachment($attachment->ID, true);

                            }

                     }

                          wp_delete_post($_POST['post_id'], true);

                }

            }  

            exit;
}
```

The code added

```
function get_attachment_id_from_src ($image_src) {
  global $wpdb;

  $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid='$image_src'";
  $id = $wpdb->get_var($query);

  return $id;

}

if(!empty($_POST['avatar_id'])  && $_POST['avatar_id'] != get_user_meta($current_user->id, 'custom_avatar', true) && empty( $_POST['remove_avatar'])) {

        update_user_meta($current_user->id, 'custom_avatar', esc_attr( $_POST['avatar_id']));

    } elseif(!empty( $_POST['remove_avatar']) && $_POST['remove_avatar'] == 1) {

                $avatar_url = get_user_meta($current_user->id, 'custom_avatar', true);

                $attachment_delete = get_attachment_id_from_src($avatar_url);

                wp_delete_attachment($attachment_delete, true);

        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'custom_avatar', '-1');

    }
```

Comment: didnt work for me :(

Comment: it worked but attachments remained

Comment: Try again I did a few changes to the function, meavy that you saw was the cache, you can avoid this with Ctrl + F5, the images should be delete in a short time

Comment: Andres i also using custom_avatar meta to store the users uploaded avatars. I am removing the avatar like that;  http://pastebin.com/7Dj9Cp9j  it removes the avatar but the uploaded files remains.  how can i add your solution to this to permanently delete the uploaded images from the server?  thanks.

Comment: Where are stored the avatars? in the uploads directory or in a custom directory created for you. A prototype of the url where is located the avatars will be fine.

Comment: They are uploaded in the same directory with normal media uploads.

Comment: I have updated the original answer, I assume that your custom field has the url of the avatar loaded, so you must add the first function which I took of the WP Trac http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16830 and next of the rest of your code.

Comment: Andres your code didnt work for deleting the custom avatar. Look at how my custom field gets the avatar; http://pastebin.com/ZV7Zubaz

Answer (score 0):

See the codex for the correct use of [wp_delete_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post), use

```
wp_delete_post( $_POST['id'], true );
```

to bypass the trash